# How to perform .rw file validation in java script or angular js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Here is this code black space validation is successfully happening while button click but .rw file validation is not happening its showing error as [TypeError: $scope.defaultMsrPath.contains is not a function ]
<----------------------HTML file ---------------->

```
<form name="myformA" novalidate>    

 <div class="modal-body">
 <h4>Enter the path to save the CPU MSR Information</h4>
 <input type="text" name="myFieldA" ng-model="defaultMsrPath" required=required class="input-large searchPath">
 <p ng-show="showMsgA && myformA.myFieldA.$error.required" style="color:#b22727">Above field should not be empty</p>
 </div>

 <div class="modal-footer">
  <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="cpuMsrSavePath()">Save</button>
  <button type="button" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
 </div>

 </form>
```

<----------------.js file----------------->

```
$scope.showMsgA = false;

$scope.cpuMsrSavePath = function(){

     if (!$scope.myformA.$valid) {
         $scope.showMsgA = true;
      }else if ($scope.defaultMsrPath.contains('.rw')&& $scope.myformA.$valid){
          alert();
      }

}
```

Comment: java is not javascript, please don't tag java in a javascript question

Comment: I tag only javascript,jquery,html and angular js not any thing else.

Comment: that's because I removed the java tag

Answer (score 0):

**Updated Answer**

in html file, pass `defaultMsrPath` variable to you `cpuMsrSavePath` function

```
<button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="cpuMsrSavePath(defaultMsrPath)">Save</button>
```

and in js file

```
$scope.cpuMsrSavePath = function(defaultMsrPath){
 if (!$scope.myformA.$valid) {
     $scope.showMsgA = true;

  }else if (defaultMsrPath.contains('.rw')&& $scope.myformA.$valid){
      alert();
  }

}
```

**Below one is when you are using file input field**

You can change your html like this

```
<input type='file' class="form-control" ngChange='onChange($event)' multiple='false' name='file' >
```

then in `onChange` function handle validation (i have used lodash `_.endsWith(_.toLower`) you can try your own.

```
onChange(event) {
    this.fileElement = event.srcElement;
    let files = this.fileElement.files;
        if(!_.endsWith(_.toLower(files[0].name), '.rw')) {
            // not .rw file
        }
}
```

Comment: i need to validate .rw file validation on button click as like how blank space validation is happening.This code will not works for me might be i done some mistake can you please help me over that.

Comment: updated the answer, pass the `defaultMsrPath` ng-model to the function.

Answer (score 0):

To perform file validation i found an a another way

```
var fname = "the file name here.xml"; 
var re = /(\.xml|\.rw|\.csv|\.html)$/i;
if(!re.exec(fname))
{
alert("File extension not supported!");
}
else
{
alert("supported")
}
```